# Does element width include padding?

Tags: css

It seems that in Internet Explorer (IE) width includes padding while in Firefox (FF) it does not.

How can I make both behave the same?

Comment: You probably need to activate standards-compliant mode. Without seeing some code, however, I can't give you any more guidance than that.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

- IE used to use the more-convenient-but-non-standard **"border-box"** box model. In this model, the width of an element includes the padding and borders. For example:
  `#foo { width: 10em; padding: 2em; border: 1em; }`
  would be `10em` wide.
- In contrast, all standards-fearing browsers default to the **"content-box"** box model. In this model, the width of an element does *not* include padding or borders. For example:
  `#foo { width: 10em; padding: 2em; border: 1em; }`
  will actually be `16em` wide: `10em` + `2em` padding for each side, + `1em` border for each edge.

If you use a modern version of IE with [valid markup](http://validator.w3.org/), a [good doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), and [appropriate headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#SetMode) it will adhere to the standard. Otherwise, you can force modern standards-compliant browsers to use "border-box" via:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*The first declaration is needed for Opera, the second is for Firefox, the third is for Webkit and Chrome.*

Here's a simple test I made years ago for testing what box-sizing declaration your browser supports: http://phrogz.net/CSS/boxsizing.html

*Note that Webkit (Safari and Chrome) do not support the `padding-box` box model via any declaration.*

Comment: +1 for mentioning both the content box and border box models. Might want to elaborate on the differences though.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the impetus to answer more rigorously. Updated.

Comment: Nice answer; I've been trying to remember (or find) the names of the different options for a couple of days now... +1 =)

Comment: No one cares about opera.

Comment: Sir, you mentionned `padding-box` for Webkit at the end of your answer. I don't find it among possible values here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp, thank you

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers See [why W3Schools sucks](http://www.w3fools.com) and then [a far better reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) which leads you to [the W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150519/#propdef-box-sizing). Don't follow any more links to W3Schools. Further, add "MDN" to your search engine queries about web standards in the future.

Comment: As of 2021, the prefixes are irrelevant for all but 0.23% of browsers - https://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing.

Answer (score 28):

A simple rule is to try to avoid using padding/margin and width property for same element. i.e. Use something similar to this

```
<div class="width-div">
     <div class="padding-div">
     ...........
     ...........
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I use this method on a regular basis and never have cross browser issues with it.

Answer (score 22):

I bumped into this question and even though it's a couple of years old, I thought I might add this in case anyone bumps into this thread.

CSS3 now has a box-sizing property. If you set, say,

```
.bigbox {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 1000px; 
    border: 5px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

your class will be 1000px wide, instead of 1030px.  This is, of course, incredibly useful for anyone who uses pixel-sized border with liquid divs, because it solves an otherwise insoluble problem.

Even better, box-sizing is supported by all major browsers except IE7 and below.  To **include** all items within the width or height dimension, set box-sizing to border-box. To **aggregate** other items to the width and/or height, which is the default, you can set box-sizing to "content-box".

I'm not sure of the current state of browser syntax, but I still include -moz and -webkit prefixes:

```
.bigbox{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Yes, and Paul Irish has a nice blog article about this here:
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: How this answer has so many upvotes when is the same answer as the accepted one which was written is 3 years  before?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a doctype declared? When I started coding html I had this problem, and it was from not having a doctype declared. My favorite is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

for those who would still have the problem, **jQuery** provided two property `outerWidth ()` and `innerWitdh ()` to know the **width** of an object with or without borders ...