# CSS How to make text align background-color top line

Tags: html, css

CSS How to make text align the background-color top line
http://jsfiddle.net/5xR8V/
(padding-top : - px not working)

```
<div class="a">
 texttext
</div>

.a{
position: absolute;
top:100px;
width: 200px;
height: 19px;
background: #000000;
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Me neither, but maybe setting `line-height:13px` could help

Comment: By the way OP, negative padding is not supported in CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974113/805556.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be at the top, but still have space at the bottom:

```
line-height:19px;
padding-bottom:2px;
```

or just the line-height if you want the background colour to be the same height as the letters. 19px will allow for capital letters - if you want it to be just lower case, you could make it smaller, maybe 13px.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're talking about?

http://jsfiddle.net/5xR8V/

`line-height:19px`

Answer (score 0):

By setting the line-height, you can move the text to the very top of the background.

```
line-height:13px;
```

Answer (score 0):

text align in CSS can have values of left, right and center. I guess you're speaking of vertical aligning or vertical filling with colors, then it's a bit weird to read "text align" in this context. ;)

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/5xR8V/2/ with less horizontal lines being completely black with no text. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Beware: this is highly dependant of the font used. By default it's serif (Times or Times New Roman most of the times except on Linux I believe), values WILL change with Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, etc