# bootstrap 4 navbar, cant remove padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to remove the padding between menu and navbar margin. I cant seem to find an answer.

```css
header nav #logo {
  padding: -10px; }
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color: red;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="60" height="60">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: `margin: -10px`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973988/why-does-css-not-support-negative-padding

Comment: "Between menu and navbar margin" -- please clarify your question

Comment: Click on the image description

Comment: Edit the question to clarify please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 [spacing utilites for padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

[Decrease Padding Navbar Example](https://www.codeply.com/go/hek9Lon9Ej)

`py-0` sets vertical (y-axis) padding to 0.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark py-0 bg-primary navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item py-0"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not the nav that had the pading, it was the body. To the body I put py-0 in his class and ready

Comment: please publish concrete code samples with solution - your answer should be a comment.