# style.marginTop in JS does not work with negative value

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I try to add the current `window.pageYOffset` value as a `marginTop` value for someone container on the page with `onclick` event. But it does not happen.

Also I want to admit, that there is no problem with adding a positive value of the `window.pageYOffset` to `marginTop`.

Here my code:

```
    let a = window.pageYOffset;

    const rightColumn = document.querySelector('.right-side__column');
    rightColumn.style.marginTop = '-' + a + 'px'; // in such way a in 
                                           // padding even equal to 0.

    // rightColumn.style.marginTop = a + 'px'; - work fine, the value is transfer normally.
```

Comment: CSS does not support negative padding

Comment: It also does not work with margin, instead of padding @brk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does CSS not support negative padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973988/why-does-css-not-support-negative-padding)

Comment: @Anuresh NO! This question about different problem!

Comment: @MaxWolfen Then `style.paddingTop in JS does not work with negative value` ==> why this title

Comment: CSS does not allow negative padding, pls refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-left)

Comment: I repeat again - the problem with marginTop as with the paddingTop are the same!  @Ahuresh
Read posts carefully before send it on the duplicate tag!

Comment: @MaxWolfen what is the value of  `window.pageYOffset`

Comment: Does this work? `let a = 0 - window.pageYOffset; /*truncated*/ rightColumn.style.marginTop = a + 'px';`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you did, try using `0 - a + "px"`.