# CSS - Margin against Margin

Tags: css

I've got an aissue with 2 divs - both rendered as blocks both have margins of 15px (top div has bottom margin, bottom has top), therefore I expect the gap between to be 30px rather than 15px, is this a correct assumption or am I going mad!?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Done a little fiddle, gap is 15px http://jsfiddle.net/RBR79/

Comment: There could be any number of things causing this – the positioning, floating, the browser, the container block... Post relevant CSS and HTML please. **edit** @thirtydot: D'oh, forgot margins collapse vertically. http://www.richinstyle.com/guides/box2.html#margin

Comment: @stslavik: It's collapsing margins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CSS box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) defines the behavior for [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), and it is expected behavior among all browsers.

[You might also find my answer to this related question to be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903549/why-do-the-css-width-and-height-properties-not-adjust-for-padding/4903697#4903697).

Answer (score 0):

Both margins will have 15px, and not sum them. If you want to add them use padding instead.

Answer (score 0):

have had the same issue and couldn't use padding as a fix.
I have managed to fix this with this little hack:

```
.btn {
    /* hack for a 2px margin */
    border-top: 2px #fff solid !important;
    /* this is important if you have a background-color
    and don't want to see it underneath the transparent border*/
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Please launch this snippet for demo:

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: rgb(48, 158, 140);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.fake-margin {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div>Margin applied is 10px on each sides</div>
<div>the first two have only 10px between them</div>
<div class="fake-margin">the last two have 10 + 10px</div>
<div class="fake-margin">= 20 px</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct - but if it's not working out you could try 'padding' instead of 'margin' - that will probably have the desired effect.

Comment: Padding and margins are completely different things, you should not use one instead of the other.

Comment: Padding should only affect a containing div. It's the space between the inside edge of the container, and the outside edge of the content.

Comment: I was under the impression he wanted 30px of space.  Padding would have done that.  Thanks for the heads up gang.

Comment: I gave the -1 not because you recommended using padding, but because you said that Paul's assumption was "correct" which it most certainly wasn't.

Comment: yep, you're right zzzzBov.  I'm running a bit behind today apparently - need more java.