# Strange extra top space in body

Tags: html, css

In this test page, the  element has a strange extra amount of space on the top:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3085200/canvasTest/index.html

I tried putting margin, padding, top all to 0 for body, and padding to 0 for html, but none of it helped.

```
html
{
    padding:0px;
}
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Margin Collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), enjoy your stay.

Comment: It seems the only benefit of this is wasting man hours debugging margin issues. Oh wait that's a drawback. -_-

Comment: most developers whom I've met, who dislike CSS, dislike it without understanding [why the box model is the way it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903549/why-do-the-css-width-and-height-properties-not-adjust-for-padding/4903697#4903697). Also, most have never read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/). It's not that hard, and definitely not a waste of your time.

Comment: I don't dislike CSS, I actually enjoy most of its decisions. I just couldn't understand the logic behind this one. =] The problem, is due to inconsistent implementations by different browsers, but, that is a problem with all standards.

Comment: Do you still have that code? If so, please edit it in. Your Dropbox link is dead so the question is useless now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this in css:

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

This is a common scenario (logo image wrapped in h1 tag):

[image]

Comment: That's a good one, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is actually caused by the margin on your `h1` element.

Answer (score 2):

You `<h1>` has default margin-top added to it, so it's pushing the `<body>` down from the top of the window.

```
body > h1:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

My console is showing a `0.67em` top margin on the `<h1>` surrounding your top element.

Try this...

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sure the experts will laugh at this. I started using Expression Web 4 and tried to place the header info for my pages into a file header.txt to include on every page. I changed the file type from html to shtml and used this line:

All okay, except for a pesky extra space at the top of the file.

The solution was this:

Tools>Page Editor Options>Authoring

Uncheck .txt under "Add a Byte Order Mark when creating or renaming UTF-8 documents with these file extensions."

I hope this helps someone else as naive as I.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to **put a display flex** on your body, it worked in my case

Hope it will help someone :)

Comment: Can you add a code snippet showing how?

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that space at the top. This often happens to me too. In my case there is a hidden break (`<br/>`) somewhere between the `<head>` and `<body>`. When you find this break and remove it, the top space will be fixed!

Answer (score -1):

```
  html > h1:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, generally your `h1`s aren't going to be a direct descendent of `html`

Answer (score -2):

I know this post is old, but I wanted to share a different solution that worked for me, for anyone that might come across this same post, looking for help, as I have.

Every solution I found seemed to be the result of an error, but I didn't have any errors, that could see. After over an hour of problem solving and piecing apart one of my past designs, I found this solution:

In the CSS for the DIV that you want attached to the top of the browser, add this one simple line:

```
#ContentContainer{

border: 1px solid transparent;

};
```

I'm not quite sure why it works or why it's needed, but it made the gap disappear.

Comment: I don’t see how this is related to the original question. The original code is unavailable now. While your problem might look similar, it is probably caused by something completely different. Please [ask] a new question if you need help.