# Setting CSS padding in negative

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML. I have a `.wrap` div which has left and right padding of 50px. Inside that div I have another div `.full`. I want to increase its default width by overcoming the padding of the `.wrap`.

I am setting its padding to -50px so that its width becomes equal to the width of the .wrap, but it does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="normal">xx</div>
        <div class="full">should be same width (300px) as wrap</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

.full{
    background: orange;
    padding: 0 -50px;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/WDS6X/

Comment: Negative padding is not allowed in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you'd need to use margin, padding is used for space on the inside.
Using

```
margin: 0 -50px;
```

instead of the padding in the .full-div works like you wanted it to, here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDS6X/1/) provided by [nienn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730122/nienn) in the comments.

For further understanding, take a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903549/why-do-the-css-width-and-height-properties-not-adjust-for-padding/4903697#4903697) containing a pretty nice explanation.