# CSS padding is take space outside

Tags: css

If i'm not mistaken, padding value take space inside the actual border and margin value take space outside actual border, right?

So, if i'm correct, this CSS setting:

```
.something { width: 400px; padding: 10px; border: 0; }
```

will stay in 400px width.

So, if I have settings like this:

```
*             { margin: 0; padding 0; border: 0px; }
.main-wrapper { width: 960px; }
.main-section { width: 720px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.sidebar      { width: 240px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.footer       { clear: both; }
```

As far as I know, the actual width for `.main-section` will be `700px` and with `20px` padding left and right. And, the actual width for `.sidebar` will be `220px` with `20px` padding left and right. So, the total width will be exactly the same as `main-wrapper` width. Like this:

```
(10px + 700px + 10px) + (10px + 220px + 10px) = 960px //.main-wrapper width
```

What I don't get it is, why the `.sidebar` can't sit right in the `.main-wrapper`'s right side? It's like padding value is taking space outside the border. So the `.main-wrapper` can't fit it's contents and then the `.sidebar` is running away ...

Why this happens?

Comment: right click > inspect element. Look at the bottom of the right panel. It will tell you your answer to the first line. Also, please try to avoid floating elements. Use positioning instead

Comment: Have a look at: [CSS does the width include the padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698054/css-does-the-width-include-the-padding)

Answer (score 10):

The initial value of [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) is `content-box`. That means

> The `width` and `height` properties are measured including only the
>   content, but not the padding, border or margin.

Instead, you may try `box-sizing: border-box`:

> The `width` and `height` properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin.

There is also `box-sizing: padding-box`, but it isn't supported by all browsers

> The `width` and `height` properties include the padding size, and do not
>   include the border or margin.

Comment: Or `padding-box` if border should not be included.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is added to the final size of the element.

```
(10px + 720px + 10px) + (10px + 240px + 10px) = 1000px
```

[image]