# Why does the result of inline-block differ between Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: css

I put elements side by side using `inline-block`.
I wanted to make the gap between elements 2px, so I set a negative margin for the `span` element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 78px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #777;
  margin-right: -2px;
  width: calc(25% - 22px);
}

span:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

---

**Question 1**. It worked with Firefox 64.0. However, when checking with Google Chrome 71.0, the last `span` element went around. Browser's default font size is 16px for Firefox and Chrome.

Also, it worked fine in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLELeZ), but it did not work properly on the stackoverflow code snippet.

Why are these problems occurring?
I have read below question, but it does not appear to be about the reason for this problem.

- [How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Screenshot in Firefox (CodePen version): [image: Screenshot in Firefox (CodePen version)]
Screenshot with Firefox (stackoverflow's run snippet version): [image: Screenshot with Firefox (stackoverflow's run snippet version)]
Screenshot in Google Chrome: [image: Screenshot in Google Chrome]

---

**Question 2**. I set `width: 25%` to make the `span` element full width. However, the horizontal width did not become full unless 22 px was subtracted from 25% (in Firefox).

How can I calculate a value of 22px?
I can't understand why `(padding-left + padding-right)*4 - negative-margin = 22px`, even though `padding-left` and `padding-right` are set in each `span` element (total 80 px).

I have read below question, but it does not appear to be about the reason for this problem.

- [CSS does the width include the padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698054/css-does-the-width-include-the-padding)

Comment: don't rely on inline-block to do this; font plays a big role here to define the space ... try a very small font-size vs a very big one to see the difference .. use flexbox or float

Comment: @TemaniAfif The value of font-size breaks the element. However, this time the font size is `16px` for both Firefox and Chrome( I wrote to Question1 ). In addition to the font size, is there anything that affects line breaks of elements?

Comment: the font it self, not only the font-size ... browser don't use the same default font-size. check this : https://jsfiddle.net/wxmyzL5q/ see how the gap is different between fonts

Comment: @TemaniAfif Indeed, by changing the font, the blank font size seems to be changing. Therefore, if you set the `font-size` property so that it does not consider the blank font size, it solves ( https://jsfiddle.net/6whdosy3/ ).It is a very interesting move.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is the number `22px` of the `calc` function set in the `width` property also calculated considering `font-size` ? The calculated value `22px` seems to be mysterious at first glance( I wrote to Question2 ).