# Why does emotion set box-sizing: border-box?

Tags: css, emotion

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698091/9181019) stating that browsers that follow standards all default to the **`"content-box"`** box model.

I'm currently using [Mantine](https://mantine.dev/pages/about/), it uses [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) to style its components. While styling something I noticed that my page isn't actually using the **`"content-box"`** box model. Then I found this element:

```html
<style data-emotion="css-global" data-s="">
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
</style>
```

Which implies that emotion sets a global **`"border-box"`** box model.

What would motivate that decision?

Comment: Because it makes things easier. This is in fact not something exclusive to emotion: many css resets include that too. Using border-box removes inconsistency in sizing expectations such that when defining width/height the border and padding widths are implied to be included. See: https://dev.to/anewman15/what-does-box-sizing-border-box-do-what-are-its-advantages-1nbb

Comment: @Terry Thanks for the link! Why is the standard content-box then?

Comment: Ask the people who made that bad decision in the early days of the internet I suppose…?